# Remove all objects with equal values from array of objects, excepted every first object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, methods

I need to leave in the array only objects with unique name values. Filter first unique objects. The rest must be removed. There's the array example:

```
var arr = [
  {name: "a", value: "1"},
  {name: "a", value: "2"},
  {name: "b", value: "1"},
  {name: "b", value: "2"},
  {name: "a", value: "3"},
  {name: "b", value: "3"},
  {name: "a", value: "4"},
  {name: "b", value: "4"},
  {name: "c", value: "5"},
]
```

I need to get something like that:

```
var arr = [
  {name: "a", value: "1"},
  {name: "b", value: "1"},
  {name: "c", value: "5"},
]
```

Would be grateful for the best way, using ES6 and newer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` and `Object.values` to only accumulate the first of any given `name`

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "a", value: "1"},
  {name: "b", value: "1"},
  {name: "a", value: "2"},
  {name: "b", value: "2"},
  {name: "a", value: "3"},
  {name: "b", value: "3"},
  {name: "a", value: "4"},
  {name: "b", value: "4"},
  {name: "c", value: "5"},
]

const result = Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, i) => (acc[i.name] ??= i, acc), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @IvanKharkovsky, if you like ES6 way you can write `reduce` like so: `arr.reduce((acc, i) => (acc[i.name] ??= i, acc), {})`

Comment: @A1exandrBelan thats a really good point. Much shorter

Comment: thank you, I'll try. Looks like It's actually shorter